# How to make a simple tool to detect double free or memory overflow in Linux for a large project?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a large embedded project that has Linux running. Also, it has various process and threads running. I can't log all the malloc and new calls as it will make the box - Embedded Set-top box sluggish. Also, sluggishness might cause a crash because of mutex time out or other things. Thus, I want to make a tool that can help to debug the issues related to memory like - memory overflow.

For example, when you do a malloc of 4 bytes. But, you write 8 bytes. This may create a problem on the other chunk of data allocated.The other chunk of data header can be tampered. Thus, free() will fail or crash. How can I make a tool to detect such issue. Also, a tool to track down the memory leaks. Is there a way to do so? I can't use valgrind as it slows down my STB. So, I want to develop my tool that can check for the memory header corruption or memory leaks. Just based on my choice, it can do either memory corruption check or memory leak detection. Also, it should be a light weight.

Comment: Well, you're not going to check for memory leak in production code, right? You're free to use any memory debugger, find and fix the error and then get rid of that debugger tool/library from your codebase.

Comment: You say you don't have much CPU time to spare. What about spare memory? Do you have an MMU/MPU?

Comment: It's impossible to run memory debuggers on the systems that has already a high load. You cannot just run the debugger. As I told you, it will sluggish the system and will have a mutex time out.

Comment: write your own malloc which has relevant logic, [A Quick Tutorial on Implementing and Debugging Malloc, Free, Calloc, and Realloc](http://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/) this is what we did, when we had similar problems

Comment: Sluggishness is part and parcel of debug builds. Do you know it will cause a mutex timeout or are you guessing it will? Also you neednt run a full blown debugger on the stb you can use a remote debugger like gdbserver. I have worked on set top boxes and in my last project my approach was to create mocks for various components to run against allowing some development and testing to occur on a regular desktop machine where full blown tools such as valgrind can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is probably no way to call this "simple".
Secondly if you are using C++ I highly suggest not using malloc/free but rather new/delete. The options for overriding those operators are much more flexible.

**C++ provides a number of tools to improve memory safety really:**

1. smart pointers (the performance cost really is worth the safety improvement)
2. Encapsulating things in classes. for example if you use std::array::at(i) it will throw an exception if your access is out of bounds. [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at)
3. lastly having proper usage of [asserts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) in your code can go a long way to catch errors.

My point is merely that you should not depend on your debugging tools to negate the necessity of using good C++ programming methods.

Ok so now next you need to override new and delete.
A google search will provide many ways to do this.
[link1](http://oroboro.com/overloading-operator-new/)
For your problem it probably makes more sense to overload delete/new globally.

**Buffer overflow detection**
This is the first part of your problem.
What you need to do is allocate additional memory in your new overloaded instruction so that there are some memory buffer regions before and after the memory and then return only the centre part.
How big a buffer is your choice.
pseudo code:

```
inline void* operator new(size_t s)
{
  void* mem = malloc(s+2*BUFFER);
  memset(mem,0x5A,s+2*BUFFER);
  return (mem+BUFFER)
}
```

At some stage in the future you need to check that the BUFFER regions kept the values of 0x5A. You should probably do this in the call to free() but you can also have your own function to do this which you call periodically. In order to speed up this process use a function like memcmp perhaps.

**Memory leak detection**
Detecting memory leaks is not trivial.
Firstly I suggest using stack-based objects when ever possible to all-together avoid allocating memory on the heap when not needed. 
The main question regarding memory leaks is to know if a certain memory block shouldn't been deleted or not.
99% of your memory leak problems can probably be solved just by using smart pointers.
However one of the most difficult memory leaks to catch is that of a growing data structure. (say for example a linked list that grows slowly over time)

Firstly in your overloaded new/malloc functions keep a list of all memory currently allocated. And also a counter of the total number of memory allocated.

Method 1: threshold detection:

Essentially every-time your program's memory usage exceeds a threshold amount you report this and increase the threshold. If your program continues to exceed thresholds as it keeps running something is wrong.

Method 2: Comparative analysis:
In pseudeo code:

```
Value1 = currentAmountOfMemoryUsed;
runSomeCode()
if (currentAmountOfMemoryUsed != Value1) reportProblem()
```

If this is possible depends a lot on what happens in runSomeCode() as some code can legally "save" up some memory for when it runs again later.

Method 3: Leak detection on program exit:

The premise is that if your code is 100% correctly written every bit of memory allocated should be freed at the time your program exists.
This method once again is not always possible because perhaps your program needs to run indefinitely and also your program might segfault because of your errors long before this can be detected.

**Compiler support**
On a lower level most compilers have some support to get into the whole memory management system but the way to handle this is 100% compiler/platform specific. [e.g. Visual Studio C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx)
This is why I highly suggest not using malloc/free directly as this is problematic for debugging in this way as well as breaks the constructor/destructor design patterns of C++.

**overriding malloc/free**
There is however a more hands-on approach to overriding malloc/free.
That is by defining your own malloc/free functions.
Typically under debugging this will then use macro's to include **FILE** and **LINE** in the call:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define myMalloc(s) myMallocImplementation(s,__FILE__,__LINE__);
#else
#define myMalloc(s) malloc(s)
#endif
```

What this allows is that your malloc implementation can then save the source location where the memory was allocated. This approach will however not catch malloc/free usage within libraries you are using.
This is a bit harder to do with new/delete calls as it would normally require some amount of digging into the call-stack at run-time to find out who called your new() function and that again is fairly compiler specific.
Also see: [MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2009/01/19/9341632.aspx)

**Memory freezing**
Given everything I like to also just mention something that is very common in safety critical code (as used in motor vehicles and/or airplanes ect)
Outside of initialization a safety-critical program is usually not allowed to use malloc/free/new/delete. So all memory allocations must happen during initialization and then once the program and then usually malloc/free is frozen in some way. Any call to malloc/free after that will cause an assert.
This can be quite a heavy limitation to work with in a C++ environment but it does make for very robust code.
Note this does nothing for buffer overflow access or invalid pointer access problems.

Comment: Memory freezing might be too strict, but whole-programe RAII is already good enough.